# Creating Routes in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I created my drawer using Materials UI and now I can't create links to other pages.I tried to set the link to  https://www.google.com/ also.But it also didn't work.
Below is the part of my code.

````
<List
          component="nav"
          aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
          className={classes.menu}
        >
          <ListItem button>
   
          <ListItemText primary="Buses" component={Link} to="/buses" />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemText primary="Condutors" />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
            <ListItemText primary="Reports" />
            {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <List component="div" disablePadding>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                <ListItemText primary="Generate Report" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
                <ListItemText primary="View Report" />
              </ListItem>

              <ListItem button>
                <ListItemText primary="Profle" />
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem button>
                <ListItemText primary="Log Out" />
              </ListItem>
            </List>
          </Collapse>
        </List>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use Link for react-router-dom its like *a* in html
or if Is for page in tour web, you can use useHistory the same module

Answer (score 0):

From react-router-dom documentation:

> Provides declarative, accessible navigation around **your application**.

You can use the normal `<a><a/>` HTML tag for referring to external links.